# variable returns undefined when attempting to read a file using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hello i am getting undefined when reading a json file using ajax file. It returns undefined:

```
var input;
$.getJSON('cake.json', function(data) {
        input = data;
    });
console.log('Result'+input);
```

but the variable input returns undefined.

Comment: File is saved properly with .json?

Comment: cake.son is typing mistake or actually mistake. try .json if mistake

Comment: You might need to put the "console.log()" inside the function after "input = data;". Depending on how this particular piece of js is loaded, the "console.log()" might be evaluated before the function.

Comment: @PareshGami yes file it saved correctly. saved on the server. working with mamp

Comment: `$.getJSON` is asynchronous, `console.log()` is run before `$.getJSON` complete execution.

Comment: @OlaNæssKaldestad sorry typo error corrected the fix

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev so console.log gets called before it retrieves the contents of the file?

Comment: Try running `console.log()` inside the function

Comment: Yes. Move `console.log()` to callback or use promise.

Comment: The accepted answer at the duplicate I linked to gives a very good explanation of what's happening here.

Comment: @ALSDMinecraft yes i can see the results when i placed console.log inside the function

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev yes i can see the results when i placed console.log inside the function

Comment: Also have a look at [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/218196)

Comment: @FelixKling so i have to write a callback function to prevent the variable from being undefined?

Comment: Well, you already have a callback function. Ajax is all about timing. Code that needs to access the response needs to be inside or called from the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
var input = [];

$.getJSON('cake.json', function(data) {
    input = data;
});

// This will likely execute BEFORE getJSON has returned 'data'
console.log('Result' + input);
```

But try this and, assuming you're actually getting data, you should see results in the console.

```
var input = [];

$.getJSON('cake.json', function(data) {
    input = data;
    console.log('Result' + input);
});
```

(Another way to debug to make sure your JSON call is working is to use the network debugger.)

If you don't need `input` to be in the global scope ([see here about scope of variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)), you can just do this:

```
$.getJSON('cake.json', function(data) {
    // do something with the 'data'
});
```

or:

```
$.getJSON('cake.json', function(data) {
    process(data);
});

function process(data) {
    // do something with data
}
```